# How do I dump certain Rows of a table in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I created a database with three tables. I now want to create a Python Code to Dump a certain row that has been created before with python.

```
sqlite> .dump Abteilung where name = Maintenance;
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Abteilung (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Funktion TEXT);
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(1,'IT','Informatik');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(2,'HR','Personal');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(3,'PR','Kommunikation');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(4,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(5,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(6,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(7,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(8,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(9,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(10,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(11,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(12,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(13,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(14,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(15,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(16,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(17,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(18,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(19,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(20,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(21,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(22,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(23,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(24,'Cleaning','Putzen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(25,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(26,'Maler','Streichen');
INSERT INTO Abteilung VALUES(27,'Maintenance','Hausmeister');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to achieve. But it's fairly trivial to query SQLite using Python, or find out how.

Look at example here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/sqlite-python-select/